# Can composer use local variables for specifying repositories version?

Tags: composer-php

I'm using composer to manage my PHP project dependencies and it uses some personal projects as dependency.
Let's say we've got this structure:

```
- Main project
---- Dep 1: dev-3.2
---- Dep 2: dev-3.2
---- Dep 3: dev-3.2
```

It needs the same version for all dependencies. Is there any way to set some kind of local variable and use it instead of defining "dev-3.2" for every subproject? For example:

```
- Main project
---- $dependencyVersion: dev-3.2
---- Dep 1: $dependencyVersion
---- Dep 2: $dependencyVersion
---- Dep 3: $dependencyVersion
```

I've tried using COMPOSER_ROOT_VERSION but it seems it's not used for this purpose. I know there is an "extra" section in composer where I can set all my custom variables, but I haven't found any way to refer to theses variables to achieve my goal.

Any idea if this can be achieved in composer?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I could achieve this by creating the tag 3.2 in Main project and in each one of the dependencies, and then using:

```
"require": {
   "Dep 1": "self.version",
   "Dep 2": "self.version",
   "Dep 3": "self.version"
}
```

This way all subprojects would download the version that Main project is currently  on.